# How to iterate using Symbol.iterator in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Currently I'm stuck in a lesson from an online course.

This is the question

```
//Implement an object named obj which has an Symbol.iterator property which iterates over every digit of the provided this.number.

const obj = {
    number: 53820391,
    [Symbol.iterator] () {
        // TODO: implement me to print out all the digits of this.number
    }
}
```

This is what I'm trying right now

```
const obj = {
    number: 53820391,
    [Symbol.iterator] () {
        // TODO: implement me to print out all the digits of this.number
        let cur = 0;
        let a = this.number.toString();
        let num = a.split();
        return{
            next() {
                for( let char of num ){
                    return{
                        value: char,
                        done: cur++ > num.length
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(obj)

for(let char of obj){
    char
}
```

I want to know where did I go wrong? and the process to solve this issue.

Comment: `next()` function creates a new context, so `this` refers not to the original object. You can `const that = this` and use `that` instead. Alternatively you can use a generator (might be easier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the simplest implementation I could think of:

```
const obj = {
    number: 53820391,
    [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
        yield* this.number.toString();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you might implement it as

```
    for (let d of this.number.toString()) {
        yield d;
    }
```

What's wrong with your code: `next()` function creates a new context, so `this` there refers to the new context, not to the original object.

To solve that you might keep a reference to the original object like `const that = this;` and use `that` reference wherever you need it.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the basic format you have so you can see the inner workings, you are pretty close. You just don't want the for loop inside `next()`. The looping will happen by whoever is calling the iterator. So something like this works:

```js
const obj = {
  number: 53820391,
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    const v = Array.from(this.number.toString())
    return {
      next: () => ({
        done: v.length === 0,
        value: v.shift()
      })
    }
  }
}

for (const i of obj) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution.

```
const obj = {
number: 53820391,
[Symbol.iterator] () {
    let index = 0
    let numStr = this.number.toString()
    return {
        next() {
            return {
                value: numStr[index],
                done: index++ >= numStr.length
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}